# Custom Authenticator for OpenID Keycloak realm

Tags: rest, authentication, openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am currently evaluating [keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) as central Identity Manager for multiple  a backend with multiple REST services (Resteasy/Wildfly).

After a lot of trial and error and reading the docu, I have succeeded in succesfully making an openid connect login into my custom keycloakrealm (analogue to this post http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/10/getting-started-with-keycloak-securing.html)

I can see the acces token + id_token coming in the response and are able to make requests to the REST services by passing these tokes.

However I can only authenticate using the credentials of the users defined in keycloak itself. However, in our reallife case, the users reside in SAP and are unknown to keycloak.

We do, however have a  javalibrary for authenticating these users over the SAPJCO connector.

Can anyone please tell me how to configure keycloak to use a "custom authentication" module for the actual authentication?

Is implementing a custom authenticator SPI (https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-developer-guide/content/v/2.1/topics/auth-spi.html) the way to go? If not, what wuold be a possible solution???

Hope you guys can help!

Reagrds,

Kim Zeevaarders
The Netherlands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can access the SAP users details via the SAPJCO connector then you could write a custom [Federation Provider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/2.4.0.Final/examples/providers/federation-provider). The provided example is rudimentary but it give the basic idea and maven dependencies.

In a nutshell you will need to extend `org.keycloak.models.UserFederationProvider` and provide methods for obtaining user details, validation of credentials and searching by attributes.  In your case you would use your SAPJCO connector to fulfil each of these functions against your existing user base.

***Update 30 May 2018***

The User Federation SPI was replaced with a new [User Storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_development/topics/user-storage.html) in release 2.5. Migration Notes are available [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#migrating-from-an-earlier-user-federation-spi)

Comment: Thx for the advice. I managed to implement it the way you suggested and it works fine! Now for the second part: how do I exactly pass the credentials to keycloak directy from within within the REST call? In the Authorization header?

Comment: The link to Federation Provider is expired.

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui I have updated the link to point to version 2.4. The Federation Provider was deprecated then removed in 2.5 and replaced with User Storage SPI.